# Which server platform to use for a simple AC unit to Google Home integration?

Tags: actions-on-google, android-things, home-automation

I have an AC unit in my home that has a Wifi interface. I also have a Google Home. I have read around what is required to do this sort of integration and using Android Things (I am an Android developer) I can bridge the two using Firebase, e.g. as described here http://nilhcem.com/android-things/google-assistant-smart-home

But I'm not liking that solution much as it's inherently insecure. The stumbling block seems to be the authentication as Google Home Smart Home integration requires me to implement an OAuth server. As far as I can see even when using Firebase to synchronise state and pass messages to the in-home system (via the Android Things device) I still need to implement a custom OAuth server and have no idea how to do that so wonder if there is a platform that might be able to do both sides of it (OAuth server, and managing state) and makes it relatively simple? Or does Firebase have a facility to provide authentication? There will only ever be one user (me) so simple authentication is all that is needed.

I'd be interested in any suggestions for an easy way to connect the Google Home Smart Home API to my AC unit's Wifi interface, but assume I need both a server somewhere, and a device locally (like an Android Things board).

Comment: This might be in topic at [iot.se]

Answer (score 0):

In other cases there might be various workarounds, but this seems a little different. 
The assistant will need acces to your Google account since you're controlling devices bound to your Google account through the Home app.

If you're not planning on deploying the Assistant app you can leave it in the test state so only you can use it. In that case you could use the standard OAuth server provided by Google:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token